# Difference between --link and --alias in overlay docker network?

Tags: networking, docker, dns

I am reading [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/bump_v1.10.3/docs/userguide/networking/configure-dns.md) official Docker 0.10.3 documentation (at this time, it is still in a branch) and it says:

```
--net-alias=ALIAS
```

> In addition to --name as described above, a container is discovered by one or more of its configured --net-alias (or --alias in docker network connect command) within the user-defined network. The embedded DNS server maintains the mapping between all of the container aliases and its IP address on a specific user-defined network. A container can have different aliases in different networks by using the --alias option in docker network connect command.

```
--link=CONTAINER_NAME:ALIAS
```

> Using this option as you run a container gives the embedded DNS an extra entry named ALIAS that points to the IP address of the container identified by CONTAINER_NAME. When using --link the embedded DNS will guarantee that localized lookup result only on that container where the --link is used. This lets processes inside the new container connect to container without without having to know its name or IP.

Does network alias from one container actually is a link from the second container in the same network?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are two differences between `--net-alias` and `--link`:

1. With `--net-alias`, one container can access the other container only if they are on the same network. In other words, in addition to `--net-alias foo` and `--net-alias bar`, you need to start both containers with `--net foobar_net` after creating the network with `docker network create foobar_net`.
2. With `--net-alias foo`, **all** containers in the same network can reach the container by using its alias `foo`. With `--link`, **only the linked container** can reach the container by using the name `foo`.

Historically, `--link` was created before `libnetwork` and all network-related features. Before `libnetwork`, all containers ran in the same network `bridge`, and `--link` only added names to `/etc/hosts`. Then, custom networks were added and [the behavior of `--link` in user-defined networks was changed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks).

See also [Legacy container links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) for more information on `--link`.

Comment: flawless answer! didn't know the difference between a single link and alias so that other containers can access it.