# Docker compose service name and hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hostname, service-name

Recently I come across a docker-compose file with the below content:

```
version: '3'
services:
  serviceA:
    image: someService
    hostname: local_serviceA
```

I know when calling different services amount the same network, we can refer to the service name. For example, we can use `http://serviceA` to call serviceA.

But what is the use of the hostname field. Can other containers call service A using `local_serviceA`.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031100/when-to-use-hostname-in-docker#:%7E:text=The%20%2D%2Dhostname%20flag%20only,the%20container%20with%20that%20name.) but don't really understand. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Can other containers call service A using local_serviceA?` => [Did you try ?](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/acea4500b0e9319f77e1929cf7e55afc)

Comment: @Zeitounator, thanks a lot. yes, service_a, local_service_a can call service_b, local_service_b and vice versa. so do they serve the same functionality? if yes, why do we need hostname field?

Comment: You don't need to define a hostname. It's just a possibility to change to a non default as an alias. Note that you can add much more hostname to the same container with the `aliases` option on a specific network. You are the only one knowing if using any of those possibility is relevant in your project context.