# Unable to reach RabbitMQ broker from Phoenix Elixir App to RabbitMQ Container Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, elixir, phoenix-framework

I built a service orchestration with docker-compose that connects an Elixir app that uses BroadayRabbitMQ to another container that uses RabbitMQ-3-Management Docker image. The problem is, even though these services are on the same network (as in I built a docker network to support them) & set the env variables. I receive "[error] Cannot connect to a RabbitMQ broker: :unknown_host" How do I get RabbitMQ to connect to my Elixir release container?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  poll_workers_app:
    container_name: coder_workers_ex
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CoderWorkersProd.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
    env_file:
      - config/docker.env
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    tty: true
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_network
  db:
    image: 'postgres:12'
    container_name: coder_workers_db
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - 'pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_network
  rabbitmq:
    hostname: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: coder_workers_rabbitmq
    env_file:
      - config/docker.env
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
      - '15692:15692'
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_network
volumes:
  pgdata:
  rabbitmq-data: {}
networks:
  rabbitmq_network:
    external:
      name: rabbitmq_network
```

**rabbit_report_pipeline.ex**

```
defmodule CoderWorkers.Pipelines.RabbitReportPipeline do
  use Broadway
  require Logger

  alias CoderWorkers.Responses.RabbitResponse
  alias CoderWorkers.Cache.Responses

  @producer BroadwayRabbitMQ.Producer

  @queue "coder.worker.rabbit_report.status"

  @connection [
    username: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_USERNAME"),
    password: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"),
    host: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_HOST")
  ]
```

.env

```
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=rabbitmq
RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest
RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
```

**error**

```
coder_workers_ex        | 20:03:25.676 [error] Cannot connect to RabbitMQ broker: :unknown_host
coder_workers_ex        | 20:03:41.300 [error] Cannot connect to RabbitMQ broker: :unknown_host
coder_workers_ex        | 20:04:10.856 [error] Cannot connect to RabbitMQ broker: :unknown_host
coder_workers_ex        | 20:04:39.142 [error] Cannot connect to RabbitMQ broker: :unknown_host
```

Answer (score 2):

I can not see how you connect from the `coder_workers_ex` to the `rabbit_mq`. So just in case:

You can connect inside the network by using the container name as the host, not the host name. That is only used inside the container, as you can read also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033828/6583529).

For instance: attaching a terminal session to `coder_workers_ex` container and  executing: `ping rabbitmq` will not work, but `ping coder_workers_rabbitmq` will.

If this does not help, then maybe show the code that connects the containers so we can try to help you better.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments by David Maze: Connecting can be done using either: comtainer_name, hostname, or service-block-name. So while this answer gives you a correct working solution, it is not the correct answer, because this was not your problem in the first place.

Comment: I'll try to ping it now

Comment: When I use the name of the container name as the host...I get an error that crashes it...I think it actually starts running, but it fails shortly after.

Comment: the credentials werent being passed. but your answer is correct.

Comment: The names of the Compose service blocks (the second-level `poll_workers_app`, `db`, and `rabbitmq` labels) are also usable as host names; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  While it's true that `hostname:` doesn't have any effect on networking, I'd still expect `rabbitmq` to work as a host name between this set of containers.

Comment: I tested it, and it seems you are right. TIL. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your docker setup is correct, it won't work because you have to use [runtime configuration](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/config-and-releases.html) (read about `config/runtime.exs`).

When you are using a attribute, in your case `@connection`, it **will always get evaluated at compile-time**.

To avoid this, there is a rule of thumb:

> If your configuration is not a **compile-time configuration**, always use a function to
> fetch the configuration.

Example:

```
def connection() do
 [
    username: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_USERNAME"),
    password: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"),
    host: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_HOST")
 ]
end
```

This should work as-is, however it is recommended to store all your configuration inside of config files. So all you have to do is create your `runtime.exs` file:

```
import Config
if config_env() == :prod do
  config :my_app, :rabbitmq_config,
    username: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_USERNAME"),
    password: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"),
    host: System.get_env("RABBITMQ_HOST")
end
```

Then, you can get the configuration using [Application.get_env/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3) or [Application.fetch_env/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#fetch_env/2), remember to **fetch configurations using functions**.

To make this easier, I would recommend using [credo](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#compile_env/3), it enforces you to use `Applicaiton.compile_env/3` in situations where you are trying to call runtime configurations at compile-time.